# Run shell commands in windows background

Tags: windows, shell

Can we run shell commands in Windows in background and check later whether it is still running or not?

For example, we have "*screen*" command in linux. Is there any other way for that too? In addition to this is there any other way to run commands in background in linux other than the screen command?

Actually, I am running the command, which when executes, displays it's own terminal, so I run it via screen command, to check it later.

Comment: Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux Alternatives:**

```
$ sleep 10 &
```

Sleeping 10 seconds in the background, creates a so-called `job`. With

```
$ jobs
```

you can list every jobs you have created.

```
$ fg 'jobnumber'
```

Fetches the selected job back to foreground.

**In Windows:**

In Windows the keywoard is *powershell*: You can create a `Job`:

```
$ Start-Job -Name MyJob -ScriptBlock{Get-Process}
```

Above command creates a Job which executes the Commands in the brackets `{...}`.

```
$ Get-Job
```

lists information like the state and ID of every Job you have started.

```
Receive-Job -Id number
```

shows the output, which the job has produced.

Comment: Just noticed, that the post is already old :-0